# Create password automatically for new users?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, users

Is it possible to automatically create a password for a new user?

Ideally, I'm looking for a plugin that, if the password is not given on user creation, would generate one and optionally email it to the user if the checkbox for this is selected. If not, then maybe just show the password after the creation of the user.

Does anyone know if there is a plugin with this behavior or similar behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and I found this plugin:

[Simple User Password Generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-user-password-generator/) (by [Jake Goldman](http://10up.com/)) - Allows administrators to generate a secure password when adding new users.

[image: generate password]

Comment: It ask for the password ONLY for Single WordPress installation! 
I just checked and for MultiSite (WPMU) installation there is no password field. So we don't need this plugin for WPMU... great :)

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of the default functionality you're describing. There's no password field on the registration form. Just username and email. The password is generated and emailed to the user.

Comment: I'm talking about admininstrative users in the admin interface. I don't use the registration form.

Comment: Same thing. It doesn't ask for a password for a new user on Users->Add New. It asks for Username and Email and Role. That's it. The password is generated.

Comment: @Otto, are you sure? I see the password fields.

Comment: Yep, pretty sure. No password fields (at least on a normal multisite install). Unless you're using a plugin or something.